# Exportable options for views_plugin_display_extender

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, views

I have trouble implementing exportable options (using standard views export) for a views_display_extender. The corresponding issue is here: https://drupal.org/node/2128119

From looking at `views_object::export_options()`, it seems to me, that the declaration of option_definition should be sufficient. But then again looking at `view::export()` I have the impression that only display handlers are called. But I don't really understand what else might get called.

Full code of the sandbox module in question is here: http://drupalcode.org/sandbox/berliner/2087181.git/tree

I would be glad about any solutions, ressources, docs or even smallest hints about this problem. I did an extensive research before posting the issue and as far as I can see from the docs, I did everything needed to make the modules options exportable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a working implementation of a views display extender in [Authcache](http://drupalcode.org/project/authcache.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/modules/authcache_views/views/authcache_views_plugin_display_extender.inc). The only difference I see between your code and mine is that I'm using `options_definition_alter` while you've implemented `option_definition`.

Comment: Ah, interesting. And the settings are exportable in this way? I will test this tomorrow.