# Reusable views behavior, but none of the known plugins

Tags: 7, views

I would like to create a reusable behavior for D7 Views 3.

E.g. the purpose could be to display exposed form and pager in one line with css float. Or it could be to move one part of the exposed form to a sidebar block.

I know I could create a pager plugin or an exposed form plugin. But what if I already chose a specific plugin for each of these? E.g. better_exposed_filters for the exposed form.

#### Theme overrides, preprocessors, CSS?

The effects I am thinking about can be achieved with overridden views-view--page.tpl.php, theme preprocessors, and css overrides.

However, the question is, what should trigger these effects?
The typical strategy would be to write e.g. a views-view--myview--page.tpl.php (and similar strategies in css and preprocessors).
But this will hardcode a specific view id, and won't be easily reusable on other views. Or I have to hardcode even more view ids.

What I want instead is to be able to activate the behavior in the views configuration. So when I clone the view, the behavior will also be activated in the clone.

#### Abuse other plugins types?

One idea I had was to "abuse" the view header plugins. So I would create a header that does not do anything by itself. But then a preprocessor would change the template for any view where this header is activated.

I am sure this works and it does provide the reusability, but it feels wrong, and will be confusing to anyone using it.

#### Custom settings with hook_form_alter()

Maybe.. a new checkbox in my view where you can enable specific extra behaviors. Is this a good idea? What would be the natural place for such a setting?

Comment: So, turns out that views_plugin_display_extender is the solution. Thanks to dawehner/dereine on IRC!

Comment: I heard that there are problems when exporting this to features, so this might be a useful read: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95812/exportable-options-for-views-plugin-display-extender

Comment: Otherwise, I will only post an "answer" once I tried this myself.